# String replace and concatenation

Tags: string, xslt, replace, concatenation, xslt-1.0

I have this structure

```
<ROWS>
  <ROW>
    <TEXT> This is a @good@ @day@ </TEXT>
    <good>great</good>
    <day>month</day>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <TEXT> This is a @good@ @day@ </TEXT>
    <good>Fun</good>
    <day>morning</day>
  </ROW>
</ROWS>
```

How do I change that to

```
<statement> This is a great month, this is a Fun morning </statement>
```

Using only XSLT 1.0?

The original XML can change tag name. But not the structure! Any ideas?

Comment: When posting XML please indent correctly.  Secondly, you are expected to make an effort to solve the problem. Please edit your post and show what you have tried so far.  For more details please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].

Comment: Which names can change and which cannot?

Comment: How is it supposed to know to change the T at the beginning of the second one to a lowercase T? Should it always change the first letter of every line but the first to lowercase?

Answer (score 3):

This seems somewhat similar to creating form letters from a template. Assuming the example is not to be meant literally, you could try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <statements>
        <xsl:for-each select="ROWS/ROW/TEXT">
            <statement>
                <xsl:call-template name="merge">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </statement>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </statements>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="merge">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="sep" select="'@'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, $sep) and contains(substring-after($string, $sep), $sep)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $sep)" />
            <xsl:variable name="placeholder" select="substring-before(substring-after($string, $sep), $sep)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="../*[name() = $placeholder]" />
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="merge">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after(substring-after($string, $sep), $sep)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given an input of:

```
<ROWS>
  <ROW>
    <TEXT>The quick brown @animal@ jumps over the @property@ dog.</TEXT>
    <animal>fox</animal>
    <property>lazy</property>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <TEXT>A journey of a @number@ miles @action@ with a single @act@.</TEXT>
    <number>thousand</number>
    <action>begins</action>
    <act>step</act>
  </ROW>
</ROWS>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<statements>
   <statement>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</statement>
   <statement>A journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step.</statement>
</statements>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the XSLT 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/); find the section on string functions.  Study the contains, substring-before, and substring-after functions.  The solution to your problem should become clear; if it doesn't, you should at least be able to get far enough on your problem to pose a question that does not look as if it could be paraphrased as "Please do my homework for me."

Comment: I appreciate the comment. and that's exactly what I will do. It was just something I need pretty quick. But now throw some live examples I have a direction on how ot approach something lie that now! Thank You!