# XSL Attribute expression notation in text nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

`value-of` is horrible. When I need to insert a large number of variable values into a text node, it really pollutes the XSL file.

Is there a way to be able to use attribute expression notation, i.e. `text text {$variable}`, on the inside of an output text node? Or at least something more concise than `value-of`?

Comment: An example of the input and desired output could be really useful here. Offhand, I would suggest using a named template.

Comment: See an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265164/string-replace-and-concatenation/22272894#22272894

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use concat.

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
  'text text ',
  $variable,
  'text text ',  
  $variable,
  'text text'
)" />
```

Comment: I was just about to add `concat()` to my answer as an 1.0/2.0 option. +1

Comment: This is probably my best option.

Comment: With XSLT 1.0 it definitely is.

Comment: There is a problem. It's interpreting literal newlines in the text strings as spaces. Is there a way to escape those?

Comment: That's because upon parsing the XSLT script, the standard rules of XML parsing apply. And these say: Literal newlines in attribute values collapse into space, character entities will be decoded. Since `select="..."` is first and foremost an XML attribute... (`0xA;` would work as well, if you prefer hex codes.)

Answer (score 5):

Not in XSLT 1.0. However, in XSLT 3.0 you can use TVTs ([text value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#text-value-templates)). They work the same as AVTs ([attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#attribute-value-templates)).

To use a TVT, add the standard attribute `xsl:expand-text="yes"` to the element. This will cause the processor to treat descendant text nodes of that element as a TVT.

Example:

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="who" select="'Dan'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="what" select="'BAM!'"/>
        <result xsl:expand-text="yes">This is {$who}'s result: {$what}</result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (using any well-formed XML as input)

```
<result>This is Dan's result: BAM!</result>
```

*Note: Tested using Saxon-PE 9.5.*

Here's a better example showing the "descendant" text nodes being evaluated...

**XML Input**

```
<test>
    <v1>one</v1>
    <v2>two</v2>
    <v3>three</v3>
</test>
```

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <result xsl:expand-text="yes">
            <value>Value of v1: {v1}</value>
            <value>Value of v2: {v2}</value>
            <value>Value of v3: {v3}</value>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<result>
   <value>Value of v1: one</value>
   <value>Value of v2: two</value>
   <value>Value of v3: three</value>
</result>
```

Comment: This is one of my favorite features of XSLT 3.0.

Comment: Though this is interesting, I am unfortunately limited to 1.0.

Comment: @Reinderien - That is very unfortunate.

Comment: @helderdarocha - I agree! I added a better example to show how descendant text nodes are evaluated.